# Tag script não é impressa com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu preciso imprimir um script utilizando jQuery porém, todo o código é impresso e o script não, alguem sabe como resolver isso? Segue código abaixo:

```
codigo = '<div id="teste"><input type="submit" id="botao" value="Send" /><script>$("#botao").click(function() { alert("test"); });</script></div>';
$('#iframe5').parent().after(codigo);
```

Comment: Se você tiver utilizando algum CMS, pode ser que o mesmo impeça inserir tags script diretamente na página.

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa "injetar" o Script dessa forma. Na verdade, isso pode criar problemas se o seletor pegar mais de um elemento no frame, duplicando os listeners.

```js
//código html a ser injetado na página
var codigo = '<div id="teste"><input type="submit" id="botao" value="Send" /></div>';

//insere o elemento no local adequado
$('#iframe5').parent().after(codigo);

//adicione um handler no botão adicionado pelo ID
$("#botao").click(function() { alert("test"); });
```

Coloquei um exemplo funcional no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qL8TV/).

Também é possível recuperar uma referência do tipo jQuery para os elementos criados e então adicionar o *listener* ao botão:

```js
//transforma código html a ser injetado na página em elementos reais com o jQuery
var codigo = $('<div id="teste"><input type="submit" id="botao" value="Send" /></div>');

//localiza o botão a adiciona o listener
codigo.find('input').click(function() { alert("test"); });

//insere o elemento no local adequado
$('#iframe5').parent().after(codigo);
```

A vantagem disso é que você não precisa fixar um `id`.

Outra abordagem é usar a função [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) do jQuery para não precisar associar o evento ao botão recém criado. Exemplo:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#botao", function() { alert("test"); });
```

Executando o código acima uma única vez na inicialização da página irá funcionar para qualquer elemento com id `botao` criado a qualquer momento.

**Nota**: tome cuidado para não criar vários elementos com um mesmo `id`. Isso não é uma boa prática e pode levar a problemas.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução aqui é criar um novo elemento `script` com javascript puro e fazer append para o elemento que você quer.

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "scriptname.js";
$("#teste").append(script);
```

Outra solução, para elementos que são carregados dinamicamente é usar o [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) para delegar o evento. Assim você pode usar este código logo de inicio ser precisar que o elemento `#botao` já esteja carregado.

```
$(document).on('click', "#botao", function() { alert("test"); });
```

**Note que** se você acrescentar vários botões, têm de lhes dar um ID único. Ou então melhor usar `class`, para não dar erros.

Answer (score 0):

O JQuery não permite tags de script embutidas no html, para conseguir algo similar, deve-se usar javascript puro:

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "scriptname.js";
$("#temp").append(script);
```

ou você pode utilizar outra função como `innerHtml` para embutir scripts.

## Editado

Alguns navegadores não lidam bem com essa situação, se quiser uma solução rápida, deve-se separar a tag de `script` na string:

```
$("#leaderBoard").html('<sc'+'ript language="javascript1.1">alert(1);</sc'+'ript>');
```